# Is this really the coefficient of determination?

Tags: r-squared

I'm currently trying to implement the method from a paper (DOI: 10.3389/fnins.2015.00308).
In short, I have $K$ classes which are spread across $N$ segments of EEG data for each channel $c$. For each segment I have projection weights $w_i$ I gained by applying a PCA. To choose which EEG channels to be used for further processing, cross condition changes are evaluated by calculating a channel-wise coefficient of determination and the $M$ channels with the highest $r^2$ values are picked.

The coefficient of determination is calculated by

$$
r_c = \frac{\sqrt{n_1 n_2}}{n_1 + n_2} \frac{mean{(w_1)} - mean{(w_2)}}{std{(w_1 \cup w_2)}}, r^2 = r \cdot r
$$

Where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of segments for two classes to be compared and $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the projection weights for said conditions. However, I'm not really sure what they really are calculating there as I remember the coefficient of determination being calculated differently.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I came across the paper where this method for channel selection is described. It's called Bi-serial Correlation Coefficient and is described in Müller, Klaus-Robert, et al. "Machine learning techniques for brain-computer interfaces." Biomed. Tech 49.1 (2004): 11-22.